# C# Wpf treeview folder explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am currently using an explorer treeview based on this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21248/A-Simple-WPF-Explorer-Tree

For this, I'm adding a dummy treeviewItem to each newly added item and load its subfolder when  I extend it.

I'd like to avoid it when a folder doesn't have any subfolders. But when I try, all of the folders doesn't appears in the treeview (for example I only load 7 folder in C: instead of 19)

I'm actually using this method to do that:

```
private void AddTVItem(object sender, string text, type theType)
{
    TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
    switch (theType)
    {
        case type.root:
            item.Header = text;
            ((TreeView)sender).Items.Add(item);
            break;

        case type.hdd:
            item.Header = text;
            item.Items.Add(dummyNode);
            item.Expanded += new RoutedEventHandler(Folder_Expanded);
            ((TreeViewItem)sender).Items.Add(item);
            break;

        case type.folder:
            item.Header = text.Substring(text.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            if (Directory.GetDirectories(text).Length != 0)
            {
                item.Items.Add(dummyNode);
                item.Expanded += new RoutedEventHandler(Folder_Expanded);
            } 
            ((TreeViewItem)sender).Items.Add(item);
            break;

    }

}
```

So with this method, I don't get all my folders, but without the test to know if the actual item have subfolder, it's working...

```
case type.folder:
    item.Header = text.Substring(text.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
    item.Items.Add(dummyNode);
    item.Expanded += new RoutedEventHandler(Folder_Expanded);
    ((TreeViewItem)sender).Items.Add(item);
    break;
```

But this way, I'm automaticaly adding a dummy item, which result in a useless arrow in front of all the folders without any subfolders...

Any idea how can I avoid adding dummy item when it's not necessary ?

Comment: have you tried taking `item.Expanded += new RoutedEventHandler(Folder_Expanded);` out of the sub directory length check?

Comment: yes, don't work either

Comment: I think your condition should be something like : `if (Directory.GetDirectories(text).Length > -1)`

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it gave me the same result...